# NSComboBox data sources and reloadData

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, datasource, nscombobox

I have an NSCombobox in my app and I have a datasource set up for it.

```
 IBOutlet NSComboBox *comboBox;
```

I also specify at some point in my program:

```
[comboBox reloadData];
```

My thought would be that after this call, I should get calls to these methods as long as I remembered to set the datasource of the combo box (which i did):

```
- (id)comboBox:(NSComboBox *)aComboBox objectValueForItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
- (NSInteger)numberOfItemsInComboBox:(NSComboBox *)aComboBox
```

But I don't.  Is this not how combo boxes work?

Comment: It looks like they can operate using a data source or an internal list. When you first populate the combo box, are those methods called?

Comment: My understanding of how a data source works is, if in IB, I link the datasource outlet from the combo box to my controller class, then in order to populate the combo box it should call those datasource methods but they never get called.

Comment: I don't use an internal list, just the data source

Comment: It sounds like you're saying they aren't getting called at all, though: neither before nor after a call to `reloadData`. (Provided you can set up whatever structures the data source methods require before the first time the combo draws, there's no need to call `reloadData` unless the data changes.)

Comment: Under **Combo Box** in IB, is **Uses Data Source** selected?

Comment: It is now...I didn't know there was a checkbox there!  All is good.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using a combo box with a data source, and provided you can set up whatever structures the data source methods require before the combo first draws, you only need to call `reloadData` if the data subsequently changes.

If the data source methods aren't being called *at all* – either before or after a call to `reloadData` – make sure the combo box is configured to use a data source. In the nib, under **Combo Box**, select **Uses Data Source**, or call `[comboBox setUsesDataSource:YES]` in code.